# Added banner to top of website but now need to adjust the "offset" for sticky navigation - updated with full code

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

**Edit #1** I added more code i found for the sicky menu in another js file.

I added a **top banner** that has 100px height to my website - I put the banner above the navigation (which becomes a sticky navigation)

Here is a screenshot of that: (no scrolling yet)
[image]

Adding this banner has caused an offset issue with the sticky navigation. Causing unwanted "white space" of about 100px (the same size as my new top banner)

Here is a screenshot of that: (when scrolling begins or when coming back to top of site)
[image]

I am editing a bigcommerce theme using their stencil framework. Here is the JS i found which i think is responsible for assigning the offset.

How do i modify it to account for an additional 100px?

```
// Supermarket
        if ($quickSearchDiv.offset().top < window.scrollY) {
            $quickSearchDiv.css('top', `${window.scrollY + $('[data-stickymenu]').height()}px`);
        }
```

And

```
 const $stickyMenus = $('[data-stickymenu]');
    if ($stickyMenus.length > 0) {
        $stickyMenus.each((i, el) => {
            $(el).data('papathemesOriginalTop', $(el).offset().top)
                .after('<div class="papathemes-stickymenu-placeholder"></div>')
                .next().height($(el).outerHeight());
        });

        $(window)
            .on('scroll', _.debounce(() => {
                if (!mq || !mq.matches) {
                    $stickyMenus.removeClass('is-sticky');
                    return;
                }

                $stickyMenus.each((i, el) => {
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(el).data('papathemesOriginalTop')) {
                        $(el).addClass('is-sticky');
                    } else {
                        $(el).removeClass('is-sticky');
                    }
                });
            }, 10))

            .on('resize', _.debounce(() => {
                $stickyMenus.each((i, el) => {
                    $(el).removeClass('is-sticky');

                    $(el).data('papathemesOriginalTop', $(el).offset().top);
                });
            }, 100));
    }
```

and

```
 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Sticky header
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------


  var $stickyMenus = jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()('[data-stickymenu]');

  if ($stickyMenus.length > 0) {
    $stickyMenus.each(function (i, el) {
      jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()(el).data('papathemesOriginalTop', jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()(el).offset().top).after('<div class="papathemes-stickymenu-placeholder"></div>').next().height(jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()(el).outerHeight());
    });
    jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()(window).on('scroll', lodash_debounce__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default()(function () {
      if (!mq || !mq.matches) {
        $stickyMenus.removeClass('is-sticky');
        return;
      }

      $stickyMenus.each(function (i, el) {
        if (jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()(window).scrollTop() > jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()(el).data('papathemesOriginalTop')) {
          jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()(el).addClass('is-sticky');
        } else {
          jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()(el).removeClass('is-sticky');
        }
      });
    }, 10)).on('resize', lodash_debounce__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default()(function () {
      $stickyMenus.each(function (i, el) {
        jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()(el).removeClass('is-sticky');
        jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()(el).data('papathemesOriginalTop', jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default()(el).offset().top);
      });
    }, 100));
  }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If your spec aligns with the browsers that support it, consider using [`position: sticky`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

Comment: can i change the css styles once position sticky is "on" ?

Comment: Yes, but it's about the same JS as what you're doing: [An event for CSS position:sticky](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/sticky-headers)